# How do I get the id out of error code using regular express in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"{"error":"Couldn't find api::with 'id'=d00c19d1-fd80-4edd-a2f4-a93d967939c6 [WHERE \"uploads\".\"entity_id\" = ?]"}"
```

I want to get 'd00c19d1-fd80-4edd-a2f4-a93d967939c' out using String.match(). Not sure how this works withe javasript.

Comment: Well, have you looked at the documentation of `match` or how regexes work? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well, you could do a substring for `'id'=` and `[WHERE` and possibly get the between.

Comment: It looks like some kind of GUID, though, there should be several varieties of regex out there for that.

Comment: Use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp as a reference or some other site, just search `String.match()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach uses a simple regex which searches for 0-9, a-f and a dash.  It could be more restrictive, but since it is not validation but extraction of the id, this is fine.

```js
// jsonMsg is a JSON encoded string
var jsonMsg = "{\"error\":\"Couldn't find api::with 'id'=d00c19d1-fd80-4edd-a2f4-a93d967939c6 [WHERE \\\"uploads\\\".\\\"entity_id\\\" = ?]\"}";

// Use a regex on jsonMsg
console.log(jsonMsg.replace(/^.*'id'=([a-f0-9-]{36}).*$/,'$1'));

// Parse jsonMsg into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonMsg);

// Use a regex on the error message in the object
console.log(obj.error.replace(/^.*'id'=([a-f0-9-]{36}).*$/,'$1'));
```